# Best way to reference data objects by in-line key according to separate sequence array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

An indexedDB `getAll` request returns an array `data` of objects, each with a two-dimensional in-line key such as `{ 'key' : [2,5], ... }`.  All the keys have the same `key[0]` and the array is returned sorted by `key[1]`; however, the `key[1]` can have gaps, due to the user having created a record and then subsequently deleting it. A back-fill method is used to re-use deleted keys but that can never ensure there are not gaps.

An array `seq` containing the sequence in which the data objects are to be displayed is also provided.  It is an array of `key[1]` values.

I want to step through the sequence array, each time getting the record from the data-object array with the matching `key[1]` value.; but there is no direct map. For example, the sequence array could be `[10,4,7,1,3,5,9]` and the data array will be `[ { 'key' : [n,1], ...}, { ['key' : [n,3],...}, { 'key' : [n,4],...}, { 'key' : [n,5],...}, { 'key' : [n,7],...}, { 'key' : [n,9],...}, { 'key' : [n,10],...} ]`.  Thus, when the third object to be displayed is that of `key[1] = 7`, I need to know that it is the fifth element in the data array.

I have been using an object to map, such as:

```
k = new Object();
data.forEach( ( v, i ) => { k[ v.key[1] ] = i; } );
```

And using it to reference as:

`seq.forEach( (v, i ) => { e = data[ k[ v ] ]; } );`

or

`for ( i = 0; i < seq.length; i++ ) {  e = data[ k[ seq[i] ] ]; };`

Is there a better way?  Thank you.

---

**Update after thinking a bit and realizing how stupid I can be at times.**

Sometimes I can be so stupid. I thought I got off track in looking at this simple issue as a task of coming up with some sort of index mapping between the `seq` and `data` arrays; and thought all that is required is to sort `data` by `key[1]` according to the sequence order provided in the `seq` array of `key[1]` values. In a sense that is correct.

Thus, object `k` would not be needed and `data` could be sorted in place, so to speak. I thought `k` was a copy of array `data` with property names equal to the desired index, and that the approach was not efficient. However, as @barmar points out below, `k` does not contain a copy of the objects in `data` but only their references. And bulding an object of references should be more efficient than sorting the array in place and actually 'moving' the data. I assume it is similar to using pointers.

I included the snippet of the sort below just for illustration, even though it is likely not as efficient, because it was interesting to someone at my lower level to build a sort function based off of an object property. The snippet illustrates how to take the example I provided to ask this question and sort it in place based on sequence order in `seq`.  It's nothing new or novel.  You'll see that `data` is in `key[1]` order as in `seq` and the property `p` are in increasing numerical order from 1 to 7 indicating their desired positions just for illustration.

Thank you.

```js
var seq = [10,4,7,1,3,5,9],

    data = [ { 'key' : [5,1], 'p' : 4 },
             { 'key' : [5,3], 'p' : 5 },
             { 'key' : [5,4], 'p' : 2 },
             { 'key' : [5,5], 'p' : 6 },
             { 'key' : [5,7], 'p' : 3 },
             { 'key' : [5,9], 'p' : 7 },
             { 'key' : [5,10], 'p' : 1 } ];
             
data.sort( ( a, b ) => { return seq.indexOf( a.key[1] ) - seq.indexOf( b.key[1] ); } );

console.log( data );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the index in `k`, put the object itself.

```
data.forEach(v => k[v.key[1]] = v);
```

Comment: Thank you. I never thought of that. I was focused on only the indices. If do so, then can just reference `k[v]` or `k[seq[i]]` instead of `data[k[v]]` and `data[k[seq[i]]]`.

Comment: Just to clarify for my own understanding, if write the object `v` instead of the index `i` to the new object `k`, then are the property values of  `k` are just references to the objects in array `data` or the actual objects?  If they are the actual objects, then would it be more efficient memory-wise to sort `data` somehow based on `seq`?

Comment: They're references. JavaScript never copies objects automatically, you need to do it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it out just to learn and see that is the case.  Do you happen to know which is more efficient for the browser, to build a mapping object to reference the corrected object in `data` array or to sort `data` in place as I added to my question?  I realize that it's most likely not even noticeable either way, but just wonder.

Comment: Using objects to map is generally more efficient. Looking up a key is O(1), searching an array is O(n), but unless it's a large array the different will be negigible. But it's also easier to use, you just have to write `obj[key]` rather than writing a loop or calling a function like `array.find()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I corrected the comments I added earlier to my question.